# Очистить стек Activity

Tags: android

Как очистить стек истории Activity?

Comment: А что за буфер то? Стек историй или что?

Comment: Да, стек истории

Comment: Там при запуске (или создании) активити можно передать флаг, который отвечает за состояние стека.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```